# can't save an object and pass to another method

Tags: jquery

I have the following code inside a table:

```
<tr class="16225">
    <td>smtp</td>
    <td>test@gmail.com</td>
    <td class="grp_memberships">&nbsp;</td>
    <td><a href''="">Edit</a> | <a href="">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

After the page has been rendered, I'm making an ajax call to get values for the "grp_memberships" cells. 
The class value I have on the `<TR>` is actually an ID.  I want to find/match rows based on this ID , and then populate the value of the grp_memberships `<td>`

I can find the row using this in the console window:

```
$('.16225')
```

That returns the entire row.  But I don't know how then to update the `<TD>` with the value...

Here's the jquery code i have right now:

```
  $.each(groups, function(i, e) {                       
        console.log(e['id'] + '-' + e['grp']);
    })
```

> e['id']

contains the value of the class that should match the

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

In the console window, I tried this:

```
 $('.16225 .grp_memberships').text('hello');
```

And that returned and updated the right cell for me.

So I tried to update my code to look like this:

```
  $.each(groups, function(i, e) {                       
        $('.' + e['id'] + ' .grp_memberships') = e['name'];
    })
```

That outputs the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

I also tried this:

```
         $("'." + e['id'] + " .grp_memberships'") = e['name'];
```

But that returns this error:

> caught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '.16233
>   .grp_memberships'

**EDIT 2:**

Latest Code:

```
$.each(groups, function(i, e) {                      
      alert(e['name']); 
      $('.' + e['id'] + ' .grp_memberships').text(e['name']);
 });
```

This displays a message box 2 times with the various names... but the corresponding rows in the table are not updated. 
:(

Comment: uhm, `$('.16225 .grp_memberships').text("something")` =

Comment: I think tr class value also dynamic?

Comment: @adeneo can you show me the answer in the context of the array? i just added more information / complete code

Comment: I have no idea what your code does? Did you try `$('.' + e['id'] + ' .' + e[grp])` or something like that ?

Comment: @adeneo please see edit 1.  I've tried to apply the code you've suggested..

Comment: Well, you have an invalid assignment, it should be `$('.' + e['id'] + ' .grp_memberships').text(e['name']);`

Comment: Well, you have an invalid assignment, it should be `$('.' + e['id'] + ' .grp_memberships').text(e['name']);`

Comment: @adeneo that doesn't return errors, but it also doesn't update the table data.  Please see EDIT 2 for more info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120546/discussion-between-happydevdays-and-adeneo).

Comment: Your edit 2 looks like it ought to work - don't know why it doesn't. But just a note: you can simplify your code a bit by using `e.id` and `e.name` instead of `e['id']` and `e['name']`.

Comment: Michael, your comment helped me to find the typo I had.  Yes, the second Edit now works... but thanks to your nice suggestion for simplifying the syntax. +1 to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to insert content into an element in the DOM you can't simply set it with the equals sign. You can use the [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function if you specifically want to add text, you can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) if you wish to add elements, etc. (These aren't the only methods, they're just some of the most common.)

For example, this should work for your code:

```
$("'." + e['id'] + " .grp_memberships'").text(e['name']);
```

Comment: hi cameron. that fails with the same error : Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '.16233 .grp_memberships'

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining what the problem in the original code was and how you've fixed it.

Comment: @Barmar, I had a problem with one the quotes basically.  but by changing  e['name'] to e.name, i was able to narrow down the problem

Comment: @Happydevdays My comment was for the author of the answer, asking him to write an answer that will be more useful for future readers with a similar problem.

Comment: @Barmar How's that? I would love any advise you have on improving my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend using array to json, ur code is doing manual is no automation, you should learn about DOM (important).

**Look a example code:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var array = [];
 for (x = 0; x < $('table tr').length; x++) {
  var id = $('table tr:nth('+x+')').attr('class');
  var object= [id];
  for (y = 0; y < $('tr:nth('+x+') td').length; y++) { 
   object.push($('tr:nth('+x+') td:nth('+y+')').text());
  }
  array.push({object});
 }
 console.log(array);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
 <table border="1">
  <tr class="16225">
   <td>smtp</td>
   <td>test@gmail.com</td>
   <td class="grp_memberships">&nbsp;</td>
   <td><a href="">Edit</a> | <a href="">Delete</a></td> <!-- removed href'' -->
  </tr>
  <tr class="16221">
   <td>http</td>
   <td>http@gmail.com</td>
   <td class="grp_memberships">&nbsp;</td>
   <td><a href="">Edit</a> | <a href="">Delete</a></td> <!-- removed href'' -->
  </tr>
  <tr class="16224">
   <td>ftp</td>
   <td>ftp@gmail.com</td>
   <td class="grp_memberships">&nbsp;</td>
   <td><a href="">Edit</a> | <a href="">Delete</a></td> <!-- removed href'' -->
  </tr>
  <tr class="16227">
   <td>mms</td>
   <td>mms@gmail.com</td>
   <td class="grp_memberships">&nbsp;</td>
   <td><a href="">Edit</a> | <a href="">Delete</a></td> <!-- removed href'' -->
  </tr>
  <tr class="16233">
   <td>pop</td>
   <td>pop@gmail.com</td>
   <td class="grp_memberships">&nbsp;</td>
   <td><a href="">Edit</a> | <a href="">Delete</a></td> <!-- removed href'' -->
  </tr>
 </table>
</body>
```

*Note: Sry bad english*